# Read excel for pre-flitered excel data in R

Tags: r, excel

My customer has a large excel data where he has applied a complicated set of filters in Excel. I was using `readxl::read_excel` to read the data into R but I found it was reading in every row and ignoring the pre-filters that were set in Excel.

Is there any way to preserve the column filtering set in Excel when loading data into R?

Comment: How many observation do you have?
can you explain the dataset, and filters?

Comment: It isn't related to the data size. If you have used excel, you might know you can filter a data set by each column (like a drop button).

Comment: I understand it, and i have worked with excel. But, you need to first load the data into RStudio, and then write a code to apply the filters. That's why i need this info

Comment: I know how to filter in R but the customer can't share the filter rules.

Comment: If your question is more of a "can this be done?" then I'm not sure.  But if your question is "how do I start working on this filtered set of data quickly in R" then just copy/paste the visible (unfiltered) data from one excel sheet to another (which will exclude the filtered-out rows), and then read-in to R that second excel sheet

Comment: It's not the most elegant strategy, but if you `Select All` and copy-paste your table into a new Excel document, only the filtered rows should be copied. You can then load this new spreadsheet into `R`

Comment: These are the solutions but not an elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I have a excel file with two columns with the following content :

```
Col1    Col2
A       N
A       N
A       N
A       N
B       M
B       M
B       M
B       M
B       M
```

I applied a filter on the second column and I have been able to extract the filtered data with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <-xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("D:/excel_File_278.xlsx")
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 

obj_Range <- Sheets[[1]]$Range("A:B")$SpecialCells(12) # 12 is to select filtered cells only
val <- obj_Range$value()
val
```

val
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "Col1"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "A"

[[1]][[3]]
[1] "A"

[[1]][[4]]
[1] "A"

[[1]][[5]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Col2"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "N"

[[2]][[3]]
[1] "N"

[[2]][[4]]
[1] "N"

[[2]][[5]]
[1] "N"