# R Issues reading xlsx with filters enabled

Tags: r, dataframe, readxl

I am using read.xlsx to read in a basic excel file - nothing fancy. Problem is, this excel file is generated from a system that has Filters enabled on the title row. This is causing the data to read in incorrectly - It's basically showing gibberish values. If I open the file in Excel, disable filters (none are enabled mind you, they're just on for the columns) and re-run the below code, it works just fine.

```
projectData = read.xlsx("projectData.xlsx", sheet = 1, startRow = 5)
```

How can I read in this file, with filters turned on, without first opening it manually and changing it? Cheers-

Comment: Could you save it as a `.csv`? Doesn't that remove all filters?

Comment: I think suggestion from the_one_neuron should work if you can turn the excel file to csv. If you want to keep the file as xlsx and read it can you provide an example of one such file?

Comment: There must be something else going on with your process. After copying `mtcars` to an excel spreadsheet and enabling the "table" (filters, theming, etc), I saved to `mt.csv`. Then `readxl::read_excel("~/Downloads/mt.xlsx", 1)` worked without an error. I then wen back into Excel, set a filter and saved the file again; when I `read_excel`'d it again, the filter was not in effect, which is not wholly a surprise to me. (It's been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52168358/3358272) without success.)

Comment: I cannot natively save the .xslx as a .csv as its generated from a system that I don't have control over. If there was a way to convert the xlsx to a csv before reading it in, using my R script, that would work. I'd be happy to provide an example file but i'm not sure where to put it?

Comment: I just found if I use `read_excel` `read.xlsx` that seems to work. Apparently that call does not get tripped up by the filters or other hidden pitfalls of the excel file I'm working with. I appreciate the help all

Answer (score 0):

`read.xlsx` was getting tripped up with filters or other hidden issues with my system-generated Excel sheet. However, when I tried `read_excel` to pull in the same file, this worked without issue.